# Windows ADFS SAML markup vs Standard SAML makeup

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, adfs, adfs2.0, adfs3.0

I have a question about SAML markup. I'm currently working on a project where I need to integrate a third-party application to work with windows ADFS.

I see in the sample SAML file they have sent me the makeup always starts with `<saml:....>`

for example:

```
<saml:Assertion ...>
 ..
</saml:Assertion>


<saml:Subject>

</saml:Subject>

<saml:Conditions 

</saml:Conditions>

<saml:AuthnStatement 

</saml:AuthnStatement> 

...... etc
```

While in Windows ADFS, the SAML file that gets generated doesn't have this saml append in it's response markup.

```
<Assertion ...>
 ..
</Assertion>


<Subject>

</Subject>

<Conditions 

</Conditions>

<AuthnStatement 

</AuthnStatement>
```

i'm getting `{"non_field_errors":["invalid_response"]}`after ADFS login, so I'm trying to isolate what causing this to happen. cloud this be a reason for it not to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my channel which has more than 10 videos explaining everything related to ADFS -https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCO-AQkOHCYZias9arGmQtOA

Also check this video, to know how you can verify my answer - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VsjhoE-M_yk

***The sample which you have received from your team, is a SAML 1.0 token, for which the saml was supposed to be used as prefix.
Below mentioned is one example. *** 
[image]

***But, if you request SAML 2.0 token, this prefix will not be available. ***

[image]